# Simple query cursor in a thread is not finding value

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite

For some reason in the following function the Cursor is not reading any marks. I don't know what I am doing wrong and I have been debugging this code for ours. When it runs it says the value of tagid and catid are both -1. No ping pong or pang :(

```
public String getCategoryNameByLawId(final int lawID){

    final String[] categoryName = {"Success"+lawID};
    final int[] tagID = {-1};
    final int[] categoryID =  {-1};

    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                openToRead();

                String Query = "SELECT * from " + Constants.TABLE_LAW_TAG;
                Cursor c1 = mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(Query, null);

                if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                    categoryName[0] = "ping";
                    while (c1.isAfterLast() == false) {
                        categoryName[0] = "pong";
                        try {
                            if (c1.getInt(c1.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_LAW_ID)) == lawID) {
                                int indexTagID = c1.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_TAG_ID);
                                tagID[0] = c1.getInt(indexTagID);
                                categoryName[0] = "pang";
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            categoryName[0] = e.getMessage();
                        }
                        c1.moveToNext();
                    }
                }
                close();
                openToRead();
                Query = "SELECT * from " + Constants.TABLE_CATEGORY_TAG;
                Cursor c2 = mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(Query, null);
                if (c2.moveToFirst()) {
                    while (c2.isAfterLast() == false) {
                        if (c2.getInt(c2.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_TAG_ID)) == tagID[0]) {
                            int indexCategoryID = c2.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_CATEGORY_ID);
                            categoryID[0] = c2.getInt(indexCategoryID);
                        }
                        c2.moveToNext();
                    }
                }

                /*
                exceptionHandler.alert(new RuntimeException(), "catid-" + categoryID[0]);

                Query = "SELECT * from " + Constants.TABLE_CATEGORY;
                Cursor c3 = mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(Query, null);

                if (c3.moveToFirst()) {
                    while (c3.isAfterLast() == false) {
                        if (c3.getInt(c3.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_CATEGORY_ID)) == categoryID[0]) {
                            int indexCategoryName = c3.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_CATEGORY_NAME);
                            categoryName[0] = c3.getString(indexCategoryName);
                        }
                        c3.moveToNext();
                    }
                }
                exceptionHandler.alert(new RuntimeException(), "catnam-" + categoryName[0]);*/

                close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                categoryName[0] ="error";
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
    return categoryName[0].toLowerCase() + " tagid: "+ tagID[0]+ " catid: "+ categoryID[0];

}
```

Comment: Has your db been created.

Comment: Yes and the Contants are correct

Comment: I'm pretty far along this project

Comment: As far as I could see error might be in `if (c1.getInt(c1.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_LAW_ID)) == lawID) {
                                int indexTagID = c1.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_TAG_ID);
                                tagID[0] = c1.getInt(indexTagID);` that is why `catid` is also not set.

Comment: Your `catId` is dependent on `tagId`. if somehow `tagId` is not set then `catId` will also be not set.

Comment: That's why I need to accurately obtain tagId >.>

Comment: that's not how threads work. you need to learn about what threads do if you are going to use them. (in a nutshell: you start your thread, but it does not execute right away. otherwise there would be no point if using a thread at all)

Answer (score 0):

`start()` just starts the thread; it does not wait for it to finish.
The problem is that the value has not *yet* been found when you're executing `return categoryName[0]...`.

Drop the `Runnable` indirection, and execute the database code directly.

If you really want to use a thread, you could wait for the thread to finish (call its `join()`), but this would not make sense because your main thread would be suspended as long as the database code is running. To be able to do other stuff in the main thread, you would have to reorganize your program so that the database code sends a separate message back to the main thread when it has the result. Have it look into [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) (which needs a content provider, though).